# What is Local and Global optimization in Compiler Design?

Tags: compiler-optimization, compiler-theory

Does the local optimization refers to one function only? And the global optimization refers to entire program?

Answer (score 4):

In the classic literature local optimization usually refers to optimization within a single basic block while global optimization refers to optimization of a complete function. Optimization of a complete program is typically referred to as whole-program optimization.